# Limit $\lim_{n\to+\infty} (1-\frac1{2^2})(1-\frac1{3^2})\cdot \cdots \cdot(1-\frac{1}{n^2})$ and series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \ln(1-\frac1{n^2})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding Value of the Infinite Product $\prod \Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\Bigr)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18179/finding-value-of-the-infinite-product-prod-bigl1-frac1n2-bigr)

Compute:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to+\infty} (1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{3^2})(1-\frac{1}{4^2})\cdot \cdots \cdot(1-\frac{1}{n^2})
\end{align*}

Well, I do so:
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} (1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{3^2})(1-\frac{1}{4^2})\cdot \cdots \cdot(1-\frac{1}{n^2})=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\prod_{j=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{j^2})$$
let $$a_n = \prod_{j=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{j^2})\quad\Rightarrow\quad \ln a_n = \ln\left(\prod_{j=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{j^2})\right)$$
so:
$$\ln\left(\prod_{j=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{j^2})\right)=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \ln (1-\frac{1}{j^2})$$
consider
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \ln(1-\frac{1}{n^2})$$
but as you study this series??

Comment: @jspecter but this series ain't same as the one for $\zeta(2)$.

Answer (score 4):

If you write it like
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{j=2}^n \frac{(j+1)(j-1)}{j^2}
$$
you get
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2}\frac{(n+1)!(n-1)!}{(n!)^2},
$$
where factorials cancel in the limit and give $\frac{1}{2}$, because a $2$ is missing in the numerator to get $(n+1)!$.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a neat form for the partial products.

Let

$$f(n)=(1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{3^2})(1-\frac{1}{4^2})\cdot \cdots \cdot(1-\frac{1}{n^2})=\prod _{k=2}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$

We show by induction that $f(n)=\frac{n+1}{2 n}$. $$f(n)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)f(n-1)=\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\cdot\frac{n}{2(n-1)}=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$

Therefore $\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(n)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n+1}{2 n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n})=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I think the last "$=f(n+1)$" is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I fixed it

Comment: This is what we would call a "telescoping" infinite product.