# Limit of this sequence? $a_1 = 1,a_{n+1} = \left(1 - 1/(n+1)^2\right)a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$a_1 = 1$

$a_{n+1} = \left[1 - \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right]a_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I've proved it converges by bounding it below (by 0) and showing it is monotonically decreasing.

How can I find its limit?

I've tried $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}$ but ran into problems.

Comment: Maybe show by induction that $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{n+1}{2n}$.

Comment: How did you derive that @AlmaArjuna ?

Comment: Just wrote down some initial terms and conjectured it.

Answer (score 3):

$a_{n+1} = {n^2 +2n \over (n+1)^2} a_n = {n+2 \over n+1} { n \over n+1} a_n$ and so
${n+1 \over n+2}  a_{n+1} = { n \over n+1} a_n$.
In particular, ${ n \over n+1} a_n =C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: Patterns like this appear in convergence & speed of convergence proofs. More usually as inequalities, but the underlying idea is to look for some 'constant'.

Comment: I don't follow your work. Can you start with the definition of $a_{n + 1}$ I gave?

Comment: I did, write $1 -{1 \over (1+n^2)} = { (n+1)^2-1 \over (n+1)^2} = {n^2+2n \over (n+1)^2}$. (I also had a typo.)

Comment: How do you have the last bit? The $= C$ part?

Comment: You need to do some work. ${ n \over n+1} a_n = { n-1 \over n+1-1} a_{n-1} = ... = {1 \over 2} a_1$.

Comment: Alas, this [was a multiduplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99537). So, better not edit a new answer (at least not here).

Comment: @copper.hat I get what you've said now, but then how does that get us the limit?

Comment: It gives you a formula for $a_n$ and the limit is easy to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Something you could try is rewriting it as the following
$$
a_{n} = (1 - \frac{1}{n^2})a_{n-1} = (\frac{(n)^2 -1}{n^2})a_{n-1}= (\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n^2})a_{n-1}
$$
and then the next steps become a little more obvious, notably using the recurrence relationship
$$
a_n = \frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n^2} \cdot \frac{(n)(n-2)}{(n-1)^2}\cdot \frac{(n-1)(n-3)}{(n-2)^2} ... \\
$$
from here you can notice that all the terms will cancel expect the first term and the last term which will leave you with:
$$
a_n = \frac{n+1}{2n}
$$
from there the you can apply the limit as you would to any other series to show that it converges to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: At the bottom, we have $n + 1$, not $n$.

Comment: the definitions are equivalent im looking at $a_n$ instead of $a_{n+1}$, its easier for me to see in that way but if you would prefer you could just add one everywhere you see n

Comment: Alas, this [was a multiduplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99537). So, better not edit a new answer (at least not here).