# How was Euler able to create an infinite product for sinc by using its roots?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, polynomials, roots, products

In the [Wikipedia page for the Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), it says that Euler, in his proof, found that

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} &=
\left(1 - \frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1 - \frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\left(1 - \frac{x}{3\pi}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{3\pi}\right) \cdots
\end{align*}$$

because the roots are at $\pm\pi, \pm2\pi, \pm3\pi, \cdots$ and finite polynomials are in this form (i.e. $(x-\text{root}_1)(x-\text{root}_2)\cdots$).

How was he able to do this?  Why does this not simply make a polynomial function that has the roots same roots of $(\sin x)/x$?  Can this method be used to make other trigonometric functions?

Comment: See Sandifer's article [Basel Problem with Integrals](http://www.maa.org/editorial/euler/How%20Euler%20Did%20It%2005%20Basel%20with%20integrals.pdf) and Dunham's [book p39s](http://books.google.fr/books?id=uKOVNvGOkhQC&pg=PA39). Fine reading,

Comment: Precisely what does _How was he able to do this?_ mean? His idea follows from the following algebra:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}&=(x-\pm \pi)(x-\pm 2\pi)\cdots\\
&=\left(\frac{x}{\pi}-\pm 1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}-\pm1\right)\cdots\\
&=\left(\frac{x}{\pi}-+1\right)\left(\frac{x}{\pi}--1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}-+1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}--1\right)\cdots\\
&=\left(\frac{x}{\pi}-1\right)\left(\frac{x}{\pi}+1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}-1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}+1\right)\cdots
\end{align}
$$

This does make a function with the same roots as and yes. (Out of letters)

Comment: @Limitless Can I use this method on any function?  What gave him the ability to do this on sinc?

Comment: @Argon, yes you can. It is a consequence of algebra. In general, if $y$ is a function in an equation $\text{something}=0$, its roots are the values that satisfy that equation. That, of course, implies that $y(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots$ where $r_i$ is the $i$th root.

Comment: @Limitless Thanks! Does this method only work if there are an infinite number of roots?  Also, why does this method give $sin x/x$ and not a different function with the same roots?

Comment: Limitless, Argon, careful What Limitless is saying is not true. It only works so simply for polynomials. For any function $f(z)$ the function $ e^z f(z) $ has the same poles and zeros as $f(z),$ how would this method distinguish between these function functions? In modern times we have the benefit of the [Weierstrass Factorization Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) which gives us the true result. Euler most likely relied on his incredible intuition for the guess, then his great calculating ability to check it's validity numerically.

Comment: @RagibZaman, my apologies! (I was presuming that it is true for functions that are not necessarily polynomials. I had never learned otherwise!) However, Euler did assume that the result worked his case.

Comment: Very interesting, chaps.  Thanks @Limitless and @RagibZaman!

Comment: @Limitless Done :).

Comment: @Argon, very much appreciated! Accepting answers helps not only yourself but the community as a whole. :)

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18179)

Comment: @Arturo: oops, thanks. The keys for those two characters on my keyboard are close that I sometimes type one when I intended the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To summarize,

*How was he able to do this?*

He lucked out, really. It was a coincidence that it worked and an intuitive guess. As Ragib Zaman said, "Euler most likely relied on his incredible intuition for the guess, then his great calculating ability to check it's validity numerically."

The derivation (though not accurate for most other functions) is:

\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}&=(x-\pm \pi)(x-\pm 2\pi)\cdots\\
&=\left(\frac{x}{\pi}-\pm 1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}-\pm1\right)\cdots\\
&=\left(\frac{x}{\pi}-+1\right)\left(\frac{x}{\pi}--1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}-+1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}--1\right)\cdots\\
&=\left(\frac{x}{\pi}-1\right)\left(\frac{x}{\pi}+1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}-1\right)\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}+1\right)\cdots\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{k\pi}-1 \right)\left(\frac{x}{k\pi}+1 \right)
\end{align}

*Why does this not simply make a polynomial function that has the roots same roots of sinx/x?*

Note that it does make a *function** with the same roots as $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. You can see this by equating the first equation with $0$.

*Can this method be used to make other trigonometric functions?*

I don't think so. From what I understand, there are six basic trigonometric functions and that's all there is. There is no specific limit on the number of trigonometric functions; rather, these six are the only ones that have caught on due to their specialness, power, and use. (You may find it intriguing that there are hyperbolic analogs of these functions: [Hyperbolic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function).)

*I do not think this function could be considered a *polynomial* function.

Comment: Euler was actually much more careful than just "let's see what the roots of $\sin(x)/x$ are and let us pretend that it is a polynomial". In his *Introduction to infinitesimal analysis* he discussed relatively carefully why it worked for $\sin x=(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/2i$ and not for $(e^{2\pi i}-1)/2i$ (a function with the same roots). Basically he said $e^{ix}=(1+ix/N)^N$ "for an infinite $N$" and then he checked that some terms were infinitely small. Perhaps not up to today's standards, but *much* more than nothing.

Comment: @user8268, I do recall there being a particular justification on Euler's part. However, the paper mentioned in Raymond Manzoni's comment gave me the impression that I put in my answer here. I suppose my interpretation was being blatantly simplistic and overly crass, however.

On the other hand, I see that [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler_attacks_the_problem) espouses a very similar train of thought to mine. Oh well. I suppose it's a historically contested issue; not a necessarily mathematical one. :)

Comment: There is [an analogous infinite product expansion for cosine](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.22). The other four usual trigonometric functions can be obtained by appropriate operations on these infinite products, including the differentiation of the logarithms of these products.

Answer (score 19):

Nearly the same question was posted here recently.  I hope this will add a little that is not in the other answers to this present question.

We know that $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=0$ when $\sin x= 0$ and $x\neq0$, and we know that $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ "$=$" $1$ when $x=0$ (I think Euler's way of saying this is that $\sin x = x$ when $x$ is infinitely small).  So this function should be $0$ when $x=\pm\pi$ or $\pm2\pi$ or $\pm3\pi$, etc., so it is
$$
\begin{align}
& \text{constant}\cdot(x-\pi)(x+\pi)(x-2\pi)(x+2\pi)(x-3\pi)(x+3\pi)\cdots \\[8pt]
& = \text{constant}\cdot(x^2-\pi^2)(x^2-4\pi^2)(x^2-9\pi^2)\cdots.
\end{align}
$$
When $x=0$, this is $(-\pi^2)(-4\pi^2)(-9\pi^2)\cdots$.  But we saw above that when $x=0$, this is $1$.  Hence we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin x}{x} & = \frac{(x^2-\pi^2)(x^2-4\pi^2)(x^2-9\pi^2)\cdots}{(-\pi^2)(-4\pi^2)(-9\pi^2)\cdots} \\[8pt]
& = \left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{9\pi^2}\right)\cdots.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Excellent second half, I couldn't find this anywhere.

Comment: +1 Thanks so much for this wonderful answer!!

Comment: I have a question actually. How do you know that there are no complex roots if you try to express $\sin x$ as a product of factors?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent : The question of how it is known that the sine function has no non-real zeros may be worth posting as a question if it hasn't appeared before. $\qquad$

Comment: Ok, I'll do that now, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: See my question and the answers provided: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941803/how-do-we-know-that-the-sine-function-has-no-non-real-roots

Comment: When $x=0$, shouldn’t the value read “constant $\times(-\pi^2)(-4\pi^2)\dots$“?