# Why is it valid to say $\frac{\sin x}x$ is the product of the linear factors given by its roots?

Tags: trigonometry, power-series, roots

When Euler solved the Basel Problem in 1735, his proof involved the fact that $\frac{\sin x}x$ is the product of the linear factors given by the roots, i.e.

$$\frac{\sin x}x=\cdots\left(1+\frac x{2\pi}\right)\left(x+\frac x\pi\right)\left(1-\frac x\pi\right)\left(1-\frac x{2\pi}\right)\cdots$$

However, one could argue that $f(x)\frac{\sin x}x=\cdots\left(1+\frac x{2\pi}\right)\left(x+\frac x\pi\right)\left(1-\frac x\pi\right)\left(1-\frac x{2\pi}\right)\cdots$ for any $f(x)$ which does not have any roots and is finite for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, since the roots of $f(x)\frac{\sin x}x$ and $\frac{\sin x}x$ are the same. An example would be $e^x\frac{\sin x}x$.

So, why is it valid to say that 
$\frac{\sin x}x=\cdots\left(1+\frac x{2\pi}\right)\left(x+\frac x\pi\right)\left(1-\frac x\pi\right)\left(1-\frac x{2\pi}\right)\cdots$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sin(x)$ infinite product formula: how did Euler prove it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674769/sinx-infinite-product-formula-how-did-euler-prove-it)

Comment: Note that they way you wrote Euler's product is not correct. The roots of $\sin x /x$ are not $1/(\pi n)$.

Comment: Euler is famous for having used hand-wavy arguments to derive results. Even within his lifetime, people were skeptical of the decomposition of $\sin$ into infinitely many roots so he provided an alternative proof of the Basel problem.

Comment: You just need to follow the chain of links from each question. $3$ rigorous proofs are provided in [(Question 157372)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157372/) using real analysis or complex analysis.