# Best method to demonstrate this formula : $ \Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}, \quad \forall x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

i'm looking for the best method to demonstrate the formula of supplements:
$$  \Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}, \quad  \forall x>0$$ 
in your opinion, what is the best  and sample method ! 
I used a residue calculation but it was very tedious!
thank you in advance !

Comment: Proof methods depend on the *definition* of $\Gamma$ you are working with, in any case you may have a look at Chapter 6 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view)

Comment: In complex analysis it is immediate that $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)-\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$  is entire, $2$-periodic, odd, and bounded on $\Re(z)\in [0,1]$, whence it is entire and bounded thus constant, the constant $0$ is found from $z=i\infty$.

Comment: Thank you,  1. i used two definitions of $\Gamma$ (Euler product and intergal representation ) ! 2. can you please elaborate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes !

First we use Euler product of $sin$ :

$$\sin(x) = x\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

Then use the Gamma development of Weistrass :

$$ \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(x)}=xe^{\gamma x}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+\frac{x}{n})e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$$

Where $\gamma$ denotes the Euler constant.

Now could you end the proof ?

Comment: Not yet ! please how to find the Euler product of $\sin$ !?

Comment: Look at it https://math.stackexchange.com/a/674790/763728 :)

Comment: :) Thank you  i really appreciate your help !