# Which functions can be expressed as an infinite product?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Consider the function $\sin(x)$ and notice that it can be expressed as an infinite product as shown here: [$\sin(x)$ infinite product formula: how did Euler prove it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674769).

I would like to know when a function can be expressed as an infinite product and when a function can't. To be more specific, for some $f(x)$ with 0 as a root of $f$, does there exist a sequence of complex numbers $r_n$ and complex constant $a$ such that $f(x)=a\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x/r_n)$. If $f$ has a root at $0$, then we should instead ask if there exists a sequence $r_n$ and constant $a$ such that $f(x)=ax\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x/r_n)$.

In general, I would like to know for which functions such a representation exists and for which functions no such representation exists.

Comment: The [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) gives you that, whenever a complex function is entire, it can be factored as a (possibly infinite) product. It can be generalized to meromorphic functions.

Comment: Also it often happens that there is an additional $\exp(g(x))$ term with $g$ entire (try with $f(x)=\exp(x)$), and/or some $\exp(x/r_n)$-looking regularization terms (try with $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^{1/2})}{x^{1/2}}$ the product over its zeros doesn't converge).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer, Does this apply to the exponential function? The exponential function is entire but has no roots.

Comment: The factorization theorem and the form of the result admits for an exponential factor

$$f(z)=z^m e^{g(z)} \prod_{n=1}^\infty E_{p_n}\!\!\left(\frac{z}{a_n}\right)$$

where the $E$'s represent elementary factors. See the Wikipedia article for more.