# Sinus as an infinite polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, polynomials

I would like to ask if someone could help me how to reach the following equation.
\begin{equation}
    \sin(x) = x\left(1-\frac{x^{2}}{\pi^{2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^{2}}{4\pi^{2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^{2}}{9\pi^{2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^{2}}{16\pi^{2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^{2}}{25\pi^{2}}\right) \cdots
\end{equation}
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is Euler's product formula for the sine function. A discussion  for it on [MSE is here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134870/how-was-euler-able-to-create-an-infinite-product-for-sinc-by-using-its-roots). EDIT: The proposed duplicate link is probably better and more detailed so I went ahead and seconded its closure vote.

Comment: Thank you very much.