# How do we know that the Sine function has no Non-Real Roots?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, proof-explanation, roots, factoring

In this question and answers ([How was Euler able to create an infinite product for sinc by using its roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134870/how-was-euler-able-to-create-an-infinite-product-for-sinc-by-using-its-roots/142039?noredirect=1#comment8126725_142039)) we use the fact that the **real** roots of $f(x)=\sin x$ occur when $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$ to obtain an infinite product for $\sin x$ in terms of of its factors.

My question is, how do we know that $f(x)=\sin x$ has no **non-real** roots?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$$\sin(x+iy)=\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y$$
Note that $\cosh y$ is never zero for $y$ a real number. Thus, if $\sin(x+iy)=0$, $\sin x=0$ (the real and imaginary parts must be identically zero). But this forces $\cos x=\pm1$, which in turn forces $\sinh y=0$ and thus $y=0$. All the roots must be real.

Answer (score 8):

Since $\sin z = \frac{1}{2i} ( e^{iz} - e^{-iz} )$, we see that $\sin z = 0$ if and only if $e^{iz} = e^{-iz}$, or $e^{2iz}=1$. Taking the modulus of both sides, we see that
$$
1 = |1| = |e^{2iz}| = e^{\Re(2iz)} = e^{-2\mathop{\rm Im} z},
$$
which implies that $-2\mathop{\rm Im} z=0$ and thus $\mathop{\rm Im} z=0$.

Comment: Another great answer, thanks!