# What does this infinitely high order polynomial expression of $\sin x$ mean?

Tags: trigonometry, roots, factoring

Since the zeroes of $\sin x$  are $0, ±π, ±2π,...$ , we can factorise sin $x$ :

$$\sin(x) = ax.(x-π).(x+π).(x-2π).(x+2π)...$$

I would be really grateful if someone could help me understand the $a$ in the expression.
and the place where I found this equation gives the next simplification as :
$$\sin(x) = x\cdot(1-x/π)\cdot(1+x/π)\cdot (1-x/2π)\cdot(1+x/2π)\dotsb$$
Since the limit as $x$ tends to $0$ of $\sin (x)/x = 1$

In the above equation shouldn't it be $x/π - 1$ and so on for the other such expressions and not the other way around and also how do you arrive at that expression? Is it by dividing each term of the factor with constant in it like $π, 2π$? but would not that change the value of the expression?

Comment: Take a look here: [How was Euler able to create an infinite product for sinc by using its roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134870/how-was-euler-able-to-create-an-infinite-product-for-sinc-by-using-its-roots)

Comment: That does help but I still do not understand why the $a$. I would be grateful if you could please help me out with that too.

Comment: In teh casse of (finite) polynomials, the roots of a polynomial uniquely define it up to a multiplicative constant. Euler thought that this also would happen for "inifite" polynomials. In general, it is not true (you need to multiply by a zero-free function, namely, exponential), but in the special case of $\sin x$, Euler's intuition was true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How was Euler able to create an infinite product for sinc by using its roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134870/how-was-euler-able-to-create-an-infinite-product-for-sinc-by-using-its-roots)