# Simplifying the product $\prod\limits_{k=2}^n \left(1-\frac1{k^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, products

Can we simplify the given product to a general law?
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{9}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right)...\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: See also [How can I find $\lim_{n \to \infty}[(1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{3^2})\cdots(1-\frac{1}{n^2})]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286798/how-can-i-find-lim-n-to-infty1-frac1221-frac132-cdots1) and [Finding Value of the Infinite Product $\prod \Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\Bigr)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18179/finding-value-of-the-infinite-product-prod-bigl1-frac1n2-bigr) Although these questions are about infinite product, the partial products are computed in some of the answers, too.

Comment: See also this post, which is about the finite product: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1464207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write, from the difference of squares,
\begin{gather*}
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\
=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)\dots\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\dots\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\frac{4}{3}\dots\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{n+1}{2n}.
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 1):

Let us show by induction you tagged that for $n\ge 2$,
$$\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)=\frac{n+1}{2n}.$$

For $n=2$, it is true since $1-\frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{3}{4}=\frac{2+1}{2\cdot 2}.$

Supposing that $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)=\frac{n+1}{2n}$ gives you
$$\begin{align}\prod_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)&=\frac{n+1}{2n}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)\\&=\frac{n+1}{2n}\cdot\frac{(n+1)^2-1}{(n+1)^2}\\&=\frac{n(n+2)}{2n(n+1)}\\&=\frac{(n+1)+1}{2(n+1)}\end{align}$$