# Evaluating limit of an infinite product

Tags: calculus, limits

The question is to  evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$$ if $$x_n=\prod_{r=2}^n \left(1-\frac{2}{r(r+1)}\right)^2.$$

I tried taking $\log$ both sides and bringing it in form of Riemann sum but could not succeed. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think logs should work here. And afterwards maybe a completing a square, substituting followed by identifying a geometric series.

Comment: @mathreader can you post a complete answer? such "I think ... should work her"-comments do not make sense on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$T(r)=1-\dfrac2{r(r+1)}=\dfrac{(r-1)(r+2)}{r(r+1)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{r-1}r}{\dfrac{r+1}{r+2}}=\dfrac{f(r-1)}{f(r+1)}$$

where $f(n)=\dfrac n{n+1}$

Set $r=2,3,\cdots,n-1,n$  to check the surviving terms

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Answer (score 2):

To state it clearly,
$$ \prod_{r=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{2}{r(r+1)}\right)=\prod_{r=2}^{n}\frac{r+2}{r+1}\cdot\prod_{r=2}^{n}\frac{r-1}{r}=\frac{n+2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{n} $$
hence the wanted limit is $\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{9}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting the square, the factor associated to $r$ is
$$\frac{r^2+r-2}{r(r+1)}=\frac{(r-1)(r+2)}{r(r+1)}.$$
The infinite product is thus
$$\left(\frac{1\cdot4}{2\cdot 3}\times
\frac{2\cdot5}{3\cdot 4}\times
\frac{3\cdot6}{4\cdot 5}\times
\frac{4\cdot7}{5\cdot 6}\times\cdots
\right)^2.$$
Do you notice something about this?