# Limit of $\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^3}\right)\dots \left(1-\frac{1}{n^n}\right)$ as $n\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

So I'm trying to solve the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^3}\right)\dots \left(1-\frac{1}{n^n}\right)$$

Now, I tried getting the squeeze theorem around this one, since it does feel like something for the squeeze theorem. The upper bound is obviously $1$, but since each term decreases the product, it may seem like this approaches zero?

Comment: Where did you come by this expression?  It converges to something in the neighborhood of $0.719$, since the multiplicands approach $1$ too quickly for the product to go to $0$.

Comment: @BrianTung It is (apparently) from a calculus introductory course workbook. A friend asked me to solve this since he was not able to do it, and neither was I.

Comment: Have you tried the standard trick of taking the $\log$ of it and analyzing it as a series?

Comment: It isn't hard to prove convergence but I think it's unlikely a closed form exists.

Comment: Is it possible the expression has been transcribed in error?

Comment: @BrianTung Indeed it was. It should be all 2nd degrees. But I'll leave the question as it is, since this is also a very interesting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{n^n}\right)
&\ge\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\prod_{n=2}^m\frac{n-1}n\frac{n+1}n\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\prod_{n=2}^m\frac{n-1}n\prod_{n=2}^m\frac{n+1}n\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1m\frac{m+1}2\\[6pt]
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$
So the product converges (that is, it is bounded away from $0$). However, numerically, the product is approximately $0.71915450096501024665446931$ and the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index) does not find anything for this number.

Comment: Thank you. I asked for the original task from the textbook, and it had all 2nd degrees, not n-th, which is a completely different thing. However, I'll leave the question as it is, since this answer refers to it.

Comment: @Transcendental: I have modified my answer. This one might be more useful to you.

Comment: Oh, but I wanted to leave this question as it is, since it's a valid question in itself, and I believe it doesn't have an answer here. The edited version is already solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18179/finding-value-of-the-infinite-product-prod-bigl1-frac1n2-bigr), and it's a much less interesting problem.

Comment: It answers the same question. However, it also answers your intended question.

Comment: Oh, I just now noticed. Thanks.